# Relationship between an account and a billing plan in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, relationships

I'm in the process of building a back-end admin panel for our customers.

I'm integrating a feature to allow users to upgrade and downgrade their monthly subscription which means adding a new model for the billing_plans table.

I'm stuck trying to get the relationship right between an account and a plan.

I have a billing_plan model:

```
class BillingPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "billing_plans"
  has_many :accounts, primary_key: 'name', foreign_key: 'audio_billing_model'
end
```

and an accounts model:

```
class Account
  has_many :contacts
  belongs_to :user, primary_key: :email, foreign_key: :billing_email_address
  has_one :billing_plan, foreign_key: 'name', primary_key: 'audio_billing_model'
end
```

I'm sure this could help other people and I'm pretty certain someone must have come across it before.

Comment: You say you want the relationship between an account and a plan, but in your code, you already have a relationship – a `BillingPlan` `has_many :accounts` and an `Account` `has_one :billing_plan`. Is your problem that you are unsure whether this is the right relationship?

Comment: Yes, I'm unsure this is the right relationship as it's not producing the desired effects.

Comment: This page describes the six types of relationships: [Ruby on Rails Guides – Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're trying to establish a `has_many` `belongs_to` relationship, simply define the primary key on the `has_many` model, then direct the `belongs_to` model to utilize that primary key as its foreign key:

```
# app/models/billing_plan.rb
class BillingPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "billing_plans" # Seems unnecessary, as the table name by default is `billing_plans`
    has_many :accounts, primary_key: 'name'
end

# app/models/account.rb
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base # Remember to subclass `ActiveRecord::Base`
  has_many :contacts
  belongs_to :user, primary_key: :email, foreign_key: :billing_email_address
  has_one :billing_plan, foreign_key: 'name'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that, although what do you mean by 'subclass ActiveRecord::Base'?

Comment: In the code you depicted, you declared the `Account` class without inheriting `ActiveRecord::Base`. However, in your class decoration, you'll want to declare `Account` as an `ActiveRecord::Base` subclass, as I've done in my code.

Comment: Ah, I'd forgot to copy and paste that. Thank you!